# How to format input for SAS's MONYY format

Tags: date, formatting, sas

I currently have a dataset with dates in the format "FY15 FEB". In attempting to format this variable for use with SAS's times and dates, I've done the following:

```
data temp;
    set pre_temp;
    yr = substr(fiscal,3,2);
    month = substr(fiscal,6,length(fiscal));
    mmmyy = month||yr;
    input mmmyy MONYY5.;
    datalines;
run;
```

So, I have the strings representing the year and corresponding month. However, running this code gives me the error "The informat $MONYY was not found or could not be loaded." Doing some background on this error tells me that it has something to do with passing the informat a value with the wrong type; what should I alter in order to get the correct output?

*Edit: I see on the SAS support page for formats that "MONYYw. expects a SAS date value as input;" given this, how do I go from strings to a different date format before this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see a $, it means character value. In this case, you're feeding SAS a character value and giving it a numeric format. SAS inserts the $ for you, but there is no such format in existence.

I'm going to ignore the datalines statement, because I'm not sure why it's there (though I do notice there is no set statement). You might have an easier time just changing your program to:

```
data temp;
    yr = substr(fiscal,3,2);
    month = substr(fiscal,6,length(fiscal));
    pre_mmmyy = strip(month)||strip(yr);
    mmmyy=input(pre_mmmyy,MONYY5.);
run;
```

you can also remove the "length(fiscal))" from the substring function. The 3rd argument to the substring function is optional, and will go to the end of the string by default.

Comment: Thanks! I'm fairly new to SAS, so I think the datalines statement was in there because I misunderstood how the input statement is supposed to work. My actual code also does include a set statement, I just omitted it from the question. Will add it back in to avoid confusion.

Comment: `lengthn()` and `substrn()` should always be used instead of `length()` and `substr()`.  They handle edge cases better, and in the case of `lengthn()` it returns `0` instead of `1` for empty strings which is consistent with every other language out there.

Comment: As a follow-up, am I understanding correctly that the issue was I had not stripped the arguments of leading/trailing blanks that was causing the issue, or was it the input() function?

Comment: it's both. Testing it on your system should show you that as well